# How to add two variables in JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have the following loop which is iterating through an array and i try to access the next position of the current position in the array.

```
for( var i in myArray){
   var temp = myArray[i+1];
}
```

The problem is that it not add the 1 with the var i but it just appends the number 1 on the i. 
Like i is 2 and i do this

```
i+1
```

the result is

```
21
```

and not 3.

Why is this so and how can i add the two variables?

Comment: `var temp = myArray[parseInt(i)+1];`

Comment: There should be jquery plugin for that :)

Comment: Reference: [Why is using “for…in” with array iteration a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/500504).

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssRUr.gif

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically you are iterating over the keys of an object (an array is an object) and the keys are [always strings (or symbol type in ES6)](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-object-type). For converting to a number, you could just add an unary `plus` in front of it for converting a stringed number to a number.

```
var temp = myArray[+i + 1];
```

You might use better the classical iteration with a counter, like

```
var i, temp;
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    temp = array[i + 1];
    // some more code
}
```

because `for ... in` iterates over all enumerable properties of the object, if exist. For more information read [Why is using “for…in” with array iteration a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500504/why-is-using-for-in-with-array-iteration-a-bad-idea)

Comment: Love the explanation that keys are always retrieved as strings :) that's something that many people will miss at first glance.

Comment: Danke :-) This is the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

Parseint should be used to add two varibles

```
var test1= parseInt(10);
var test2= parseInt(20);

alert(test1+test2); // should now alert 30
```

This is how you can add two variables in Javascript....